# ionic 3 : Facebookconnect.xml not found error, during ionic nuild --prod --release

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I am trying to build my ionic app for Android using this command : 
**ionic cordova build --prod --release**

But i always get this error :
config file res/values/facebookconnect.xml requested for changes not found at mobile-v4\platforms\android\res\values\facebookconnect.xml, ignoring

Mobile_v4 is the root directory of my project.

I removed android platform of the project and i re-installed again using the following commands

**ionic cordova platform rm android**

**ionic cordova platform add android@latest**

I also tried to remove the plugin facebook4 from my project, but the same error appear preventing, the removal. I used this command :

**ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-facebook4**

```
here is the content of package.json file

{
"name": "name",
"version": "2.0.1",
"author": "site",
"homepage": "site",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
  "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
  "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
  "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
  "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
  "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
 },
 "dependencies": {
     "@angular-devkit/build-optimizer": "^0.13.1",
     "@angular/animations": "5.2.10",
      "@angular/common": "5.2.10",
      "@angular/compiler": "5.2.10",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.10",
        "@angular/core": "5.2.10",
        "@angular/fire": "^5.1.1",
        "@angular/forms": "5.2.10",
        "@angular/http": "5.2.10",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.10",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.10",
        "@ionic-native/admob-free": "^4.20.0",
        "@ionic-native/admob-pro": "^4.20.0",
        "@ionic-native/app-version": "^4.20.0",
        "@ionic-native/barcode-scanner": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/browser-tab": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/facebook": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/firebase": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-plus": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/instagram": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/local-notifications": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/open-native-settings": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/youtube-video-player": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "angular-pipes": "^8.1.1",
    "angularfire2": "^5.1.1",
    "cordova-admob-sdk": "^0.17.0",
    "cordova-android": "7.1.4",
    "cordova-instagram-plugin": "^0.5.7",
    "cordova-ios": "^4.5.5",
    "cordova-multidex": "git+https://github.com/jwall149/cordova-multidex.git",
    "cordova-open-native-settings": "^1.5.2",
    "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "^1.7.2",
    "cordova-plugin-admob-free": "^0.17.4",
    "cordova-plugin-admobpro": "^2.37.2",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-badge": "^0.8.8",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-document-viewer": "^0.9.10",
    "cordova-plugin-extension": "^1.5.4",
    "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "^4.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase": "^2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-googleplus": "^7.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^3.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^3.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-local-notification": "^0.9.0-beta.2",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^5.4.4",
    "cordova-plugin-youtube-video-player": "^1.0.6",
    "cordova-promise-polyfill": "0.0.2",
    "cordova-universal-clipboard": "git+https://github.com/Visigo/CordovaClipboard.git",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "firebase": "^5.8.2",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionic-img-viewer": "^2.9.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "me.tonny.cordova.plugins.multidex": "https://github.com/jwall149/cordova-multidex",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^5.2.3",
    "ng2-simple-timer": "^1.3.5",
    "ngx-moment": "^3.3.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.11",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
    "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.2",
    "@ionic/lab": "1.0.18",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
  },
  "description": "237 Actu Mobile App",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-admob-free": {},
      "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "24.1.1+"
      },
      "cordova-instagram-plugin": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
      "cordova-open-native-settings": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-youtube-video-player": {},
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-document-viewer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-local-notification": {},
      "cordova-plugin-firebase": {},
      "cordova-universal-clipboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-admobpro": {
        "PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION": "16.0.0"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-facebook4": {
        "APP_ID": "appid",
        "APP_NAME": "appname",
        "FACEBOOK_HYBRID_APP_EVENTS": "false",
        "FACEBOOK_ANDROID_SDK_VERSION": "4.38.1"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-googleplus": {
        "REVERSED_CLIENT_ID": "id",
        "PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION": "11.8.0"
      },
      "me.tonny.cordova.plugins.multidex": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "ios"
    ]
  }
}
```

So when i build, the build succed, but the app crashe directly after installation, and the error :

```
config file res/values/facebookconnect.xml requested for changes not found 
at mobile-v4\platforms\android\res\values\facebookconnect.xml, appear when i try to build, but it do not stop the building process.
```

I Want to remove this error and be able to open the app once installed on the phone. Actually, after installation, the app crashe when i try to open it.